# How to avoid php breaking umlaut characters when loading a xml file?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I've got an xml to parse with php, that contains some umlaut characters. 
Every node that contains a string has the string wrapped in a cdata tag, but my problem starts before parsing the xml: when I load the file (I've also tried to print out the contents of the file with file_get_contests, same result), the umlaut characters get broken, so for example ü becomes Ã¼. Running a htmlentities() is futile, as the characters are already broken at that point. The xml encode is utf-8, so I don't know what else to do to avoid this problem. Anyone can help me?

Edit:
xml sample 'locations.xml':

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locations>
  <location>
    <id>481</id>
    <city><![CDATA[Zürich]]></city>
  </location>
</locations>
```

php code:

```
function parseLocations(){
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('locations.xml');
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$data = array();
    $locations = $xml->childNodes->item(0);
    for($i=0; $i<$locations->childNodes->length; $i++){
        $location = $locations->childNodes->item($i);
        if($location->nodeName=="location"){
            $tmp = parseVenue($location);
            $data[] = $tmp;
        }
    }
    echo var_export($data, true); 
}

function parseVenue($location){
    //I need to exclude some of the nodes
    $exclude = array('#text'); 
    $data = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$location->childNodes->length; $i++){
        $tag = $location->childNodes->item($i);
        if(!in_array($tag->nodeName, $exclude)){
            $data[$tag->nodeName] = $tag->nodeValue;
        }

    }
    return $data;
}
```

echoed output:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '481', 'city' => 'ZÃ¼rich'), )
```

Comment: not sure if it will help but have you tried setting the header in the php script? `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Can you provide your code please?

Comment: PHP does not break characters when "loading" files. You simply have an output problem. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: I forgot: this is happening in a class, and I need to parse the xml only to save the data in the db (parse and save are working)

Comment: By "save are working", do you mean that the "correct" character can be correctly saved in DB?

Comment: no, the correct character could not be saved, it's the same as the output posted above. By "parse and save are working" I meant that I got no errors in the execution

Comment: possible duplicate of [DomDocument encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048367/domdocument-encoding)